# Multiply two 0, 1 rasters together

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I am trying to use the Raster Calculator to multiply 2 rasters together.  They were created by using the raster calculator to keep values exceeding a threshold in two other rasters.  I have tried numerous combinations but always end up with zeros everywhere.

I have 2 rasters A1 and B1 of the same area.  I want to locate areas where A1 > 5 and 30 <= B1 <= 45.

I could not figure out how to use AND or OR commands in the Raster Calculator (the RasterCalc plugin suggested elsewhere doesn't appear to still be available).

I created two new rasters A2 and B2, using the commands

```
("A1" > 5)    {saved as A2}

("B1" <=45 )* "B1"   {saved as B2a}
(B2a >= 35)          {saved as B2}
```

I now have 2 rasters that are 0,1 values (or rather 0.999000).  I want to multiply these together.  I have tried wrapping them in float(), or using float with the above commands to see if that made a difference (it didn't).

If I look at the rasters/use the inspection tool  I can see that there are regions where both A2 and B2 are 1 - yet any multiplication gives only 0 as the output, any addition gives only 0 or 1.

I have not been able to find any reason as to why this might be happening.

If I simply multiply the two original rasters A1 and B1 this works as expected, so it does not appear to be multiplication that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the "A1@1" notation. This tells QGIS to use band 1 of raster A1.

It looks as if Raster Calculator allows you to just use A1, but the end results are all 1 (at least for me, QGIS 2.18.10), or all 0 if I use "A1".

You should be able to do this in one step without needing multiple intermediate rasters.

```
A1 > 5 and 30 <= B1 <= 45
```

should be doable as

```
( ("A1@1" > 5) + ("B1@1" >= 30) + ("B1@1"<=45) ) = 3
```

or as

```
( ("A1@1" > 5) * ("B1@1" >= 30) * ("B1@1"<=45) )
```

this is how I convert boolean logic into raster calc terms:-

```
a and b = a*b
a or b = (a+b)>0
```

Also, the fact you're seeing 0.99 suggests you need to use **Contrast Enhancement**, Stretch to min/max, and <kbd>Load</kbd> min/max values. That should fix the legend to show 0/1 and show the raster in black and white.

You also mentioned the **rastercalc** plugin. This has vanished from the Plugin Manager, it seems to [still be  available](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/rastercalc/). The source is no longer available, it would need to be installed manually, and it's tagged as being for QGIS 1.x , so I suspect it's been withdrawn. At the time, QGIS raster calculator was a lot less powerful. I think most of those features and functions are available via **r.mapcalc** , SAGA's **Grid Calculator** and indeed QGIS Raster Calculator itself.

Comment: I tried both the addition and multiplication options - the multiplication gives everything as 0, the addition everything as 1 or 2 - but not 3.

I was selecting the rasters from a list, so the @1 was automatically there (sorry didn't put in the question) - the actual raster names are much larger.

Comment: if not for the fact that the inspection tool clearly shows the two (intermediate) layers as 1 when I click on some spots I'd be thinking that my criteria were never met.